# Glob pattern to ignore certain .dot.js files

Tags: javascript, glob, minimatch

I am looking for a glob pattern that excludes certain parts of the file name. For example, I want to get all `*.js` files but exclude all `*.map.js` files.

```
/hello/world.js // match
/hello/world.map.js // no match
/hello/world.test.js // match
```

I thought using a not pattern such as this `/**/*!(.map).js` would work but it still matches all three of the paths above.

I'm curious if this is possible without using an `ignore` pattern option. Thanks!

Comment: Use regex not operator for glob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I've come up with:

```
**/!(*.map.js|!(*.js))
```

[image]

Here is the link to the playground:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tools/glob?comments=true&glob=%2A%2A%2F%21%28%2A.map.js%7C%21%28%2A.js%29%29&matches=false&tests=%2Fhello%2Fworld.js&tests=%2Fhello%2Fworld-test.js&tests=test.js&tests=%2Ffoo%2Fbar.txt&tests=foo.map.js&tests=%2Fhello%2Fworld.map.js&tests=%2Ffoo%2F